# creating multiple objects of same type when number needed is unknown?

Tags: c++

I am working on a combat game for my c++ class.  We have made 5 different fighter types and are having them battle.  The fighters are all defined via polymorphism.

This week, we are having the user create linked lists of fighters and having them battle.  Problem is, I can't figure out how to allow for different fighters of the same type.

For example, if first player chooses a ninja for his first fighter and a ninja for his second as well, if the first ninja dies, the second one starts off dead because they're the same object.

In simpler versions of the program, I managed to get around this by just defining multiple different objects, for example:

```
 Fighter Ninja (strength = 20, attack = 2, defense = 1);
 Fighter Ninja2 (strength = 20, attack = 2, defense = 1);
```

Not my actual code, but you get the idea.  If there were two ninjas, they were different objects and so had different strengths.  If one lost all of their strength, the other, being a different object, would have the same strength.

But for this version, the user gets to determine how many rounds there are.  I cant just define an unlimited number of objects.  So how can I make it that I just define each object once, and create new instances of it every time it's created?

As I said, this is for a class so I'm not looking for code as much as I'm looking for... like, I don't even know where to start.  I guess I'm looking for someone to say, "You do it like this" and then let me figure out the code?  Or something?  Essentially I just don't want to be cheating by having the coding done for me.

thanks!!

Comment: Open your C++ book to the chapter that describes the `std::vector` template, and start reading.

Comment: If you're learning about linked lists, that's how you should do it. You write a loop that creates each `Fighter` and adds it to the list.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Not so simple if it is a polymorphic hierarchy

Comment: ok, I will look into vectors.  We learned about them a while ago, I guess I'm not understanding how vectors will separate the objects.   The way I have it set up now is that I'm passing pointers through to my fighting functions.  So the issue is that whenever I create a ninja, I have to point to it.  I guess I just don't see how to make a new ninja and assign that ninja to a different address as a completely different object.  In the meantime, I will look into vectors because maybe there's something in vectors that does this?  thanks!!

Comment: if vectors aren't the simple answer using polymorphism.... I have no idea where I should be looking  :(

Comment: The way you are thinking about this right now is probably something like "I need some number of fighters, each one with a different number, so the first one will be `fighter0`, then when I need another I will create `fighter1`. Then when I need a third I create a variable `fighter2` etc. This is a common early problem for programmers.
Instead you want a sequence of fighters that you then access as `fighters[0]`, `fighters[1]`, and `fighters[2]`. This works because you can also have `fighters[i]` inside of a for loop, or use any variable to pick a fighter

Comment: if you erase `fighters[1]` from your container, then `fighters[2]` takes its place (everything slides over by 1. The way you'd do this with a vector is `std::vector<Fighter> fighters;` and call `fighters.push_back(Fighter(20, 2, 1);` to add a new one to the back. However, your assignment is to implement your own linked list, a vector will be helpful for learning this fundamental concept but you can't use it in your final submission.